# How to compare two letter to see they are the same or not in clojure

Tags: clojure

I want to compare the first letter in a list with a given letter, for instance:

```
user=> (= (first '(D D D)) \D)
false

user=> (= (first '(D D D)) "D")
false
```

I think these two methods should return true, but the results are false.  I am wonderign how to compare these two letters. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`'(D D D)` is list of symbols.

`(= (first '(D D D)) 'D) ; -> true`

or

`(= (first '(\D \D \D)) \D); -> true`

Comment: I think Ds in the list are string, so I compare them with "D".

Comment: Nope, they are symbols.  Try this: `(map type '(D D D))` in your REPL.

Comment: How about this one:
`(println opp-history) (if (= (first opp-history) 'D) true false))` the out of println is (D C D). The the result is false. Can you explain that? Thank you so much!

Comment: What is opp-history?  Why are you wrapping a boolean comparison in an if statement?  What does this have to do with the original question?

Comment: Please try using `prn` instead of `println` and then paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

Character literals are written  as `\a \b \c` in Clojure.

As said, you are using Symbols. Try `(type 'D)` and `(type \D)` in your REPL.